# Techniques for placing components on PCB's

Tags: pcb-design

I know that placing components is quite an art rather than following some set of rules to get the job done, but I am looking for some references about the topic.

I already saw [this tutorial](http://www.alternatezone.com/electronics/files/PCBDesignTutorialRevA.pdf) and it is pretty much useful, but one resource is never enough. So any suggestions please?

Answer (score 12):

Here are some of the links and documents I have saved over time:

[Henry Ott's site](http://www.hottconsultants.com/) - lots of good stuff here
[Electromagnetic Compatibility Engineering - Henry Ott](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Electromagnetic-Compatibility-Engineering-Henry-Ott/dp/0470189304) - the best book I have read on high speed layout and EMI issues.
[PCB Design for Manufacture Blog](http://www.eevblog.com/2010/11/15/eevblog-127-pcb-design-for-manufacture-tutorial/) (EEVBlog - David Jones)
[Wikibooks - PCB layout](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Practical_Electronics/PCB_Layout)
[PCB Layout Checklist](http://www.volersystems.com/v-2010-issue-1/pcb-layout-checklist) (from one PCB manufacturer, but useful general list)
[High Speed Layout Guidelines - TI](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/scaa082/scaa082.pdf)
[High Speed Amplifier Techniques - Linear Tech AN47](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/application-note/an47fa.pdf) - by the late great Jim Wiliiams
[A Practical Guide to High Speed PCB Layout](http://www.analog.com/library/analogDialogue/archives/39-09/layout.pdf)
[Hardware Design Techniques - Chapter 9](http://www.analog.com/library/analogDialogue/archives/39-06/Chapter%209%20Hardware%20Design%20Techniques%20F.pdf)
[Hardware Design Techniques - Section 9](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/seminars_webcasts/36904322486563Section9.pdf)
[Hardware Design Techniques - Section 10](http://ecesrd.seas.gwu.edu/references/ad/Chapter%2010%20%28Kester,%20Mixed-signal%20and%20DSP,%200750676116%29.pdf)
[Hardware Design Techniques - Section 7](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/seminars_webcasts/36708482583117227505484256002sect7a.pdf)
[Analog Dialog Archives](http://www.analog.com/library/analogDialogue/archives.html)
[HP Journal Archives](http://www.hpl.hp.com/hpjournal/pdfs/IssuePDFs/hpjindex.html)

Answer (score 1):

If the above links are not enough brain food, I would also like to point you to a very informative blog about harware design. Specially one video about placing hardware components.

[well done blog (by fedevel)](http://www.fedevel.com/welldoneblog/2012/09/altium-designer-component-placement-tutorial/)